# include_once failed to open stream: No such file or directory - Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, magento

just a newbie question to but I don't know what to do with this error.

http://mobitel.esy.es/

> Warning:
>   include_once(/home/u320415047/public_html/wp-content/themes/thestore/lib/thestore-metaboxes.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/u320415047/public_html/wp-content/themes/thestore/functions.php
>   on line 8
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/home/u320415047/public_html/wp-content/themes/thestore/lib/thestore-metaboxes.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in
>   /home/u320415047/public_html/wp-content/themes/thestore/functions.php
>   on line 8
>
> Warning:
>   include_once(/home/u320415047/public_html/wp-content/themes/thestore/lib/custom-config.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   /home/u320415047/public_html/wp-content/themes/thestore/functions.php
>   on line 9
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
>   '/home/u320415047/public_html/wp-content/themes/thestore/lib/custom-config.php'
>   for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/php-5.5/pear') in
>   /home/u320415047/public_html/wp-content/themes/thestore/functions.php
>   on line 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like part of your theme got corrupted or didn't upload properly. It's telling you you're missing some files it's trying to include:

- wp-content/themes/thestore/lib/custom-config.php
- wp-content/themes/thestore/lib/thestore-metaboxes.php

Double-check that those files are there, and if not try re-installing your theme

Comment: Will do sir :) Thanks

Comment: This solve my problem thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress when you include files in functions.php, you must  reference the correct filepath, using the builtin  get_template_directory() function

```
include( get_template_directory() .'/file.php' );
```